# Change DIV Color Using Color Picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jscolor

I am banging my head against the wall here. This code has no reason not to work but it does not.

I want the user to be able to pick a color using jscolor (I don't want to use `type="color"` because it may not work for some of my users). Once they pick a color it needs to change the `div` `background-color`.

When I use `type="color"` in the input, it works. But it will not work with the jscolor script.

My Code:

**Javascript**:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(window).load(function () {
        $('#bgcolor').on('change', function (e) {
            var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
            var valueSelected = this.value;
            $(".background").css("background-color", valueSelected);
        });
    });
</script>
```

**HTML**: (input)

```
<input style="width:100px;" class="jscolor {width:243, height:150, position:'right',
borderColor:'#FFF', insetColor:'#FFF', backgroundColor:'#666'}" id="bgcolor" name="bgcolor" value="2e2e2e" />
```

**HTML**: (the div it should change)

```
 <div id="background" class="background" style="position: absolute; 
       background-color: #2e2e2e; width: 247px; height: 335px; 
       overflow: scroll; overflow-x: hidden;">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have three issues in your code.

1) `>` is coming at the end of your script which you should remove.

2) You are trying to use a class selector to select your `background` div where you should use an `ID` selector as `$("#background")`

3) You should prefix an `#` infront of your `valueSelected` value. (It should be `var valueSelected = '#' +this.value;`)

**Working DEMO:** https://jsfiddle.net/7g7Lh2L2/2/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much. I did not even see the > lol. Just tired of messing with it and overlooked it. This is working perfect now.

Answer (score 0):

1. Imported the `jscolor.js` from: http://jscolor.com
2. Seperated the data from class name to an attribute `data-jscolor`, based on the demo.

Code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jscolor.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#bgcolor').on('change', function (e) {

            var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
            var valueSelected = this.value;
            $(".background").css("background-color", valueSelected);
        });
    });
</script>
<input style="width:100px;" class="jscolor" data-jscolor="{width:243, height:150, position:'right',
borderColor:'#FFF', insetColor:'#FFF', backgroundColor:'#666'}" id="bgcolor" name="bgcolor" value="2e2e2e" />

<div id="background" class="background" style="position: absolute; background-color: #2e2e2e; width: 247px; height: 335px; overflow: scroll; overflow-x: hidden;"></div>
```